# CSS & JS: How to enable single-page scroll on half of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a tyro in web-development so please bear my silly questions, I will be very grateful.
I intend to use **single-page scroll on half of webpage** and am not even sure if this is achieved through CSS or JS. As a bonus, I would also prefer to get the **parallax effect** as shown [here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html#firstPage) .

Please direct me to the correct documentation pages of bootstrap or jQuery (whatever is applicable, perhaps both); so that I can research in detail. Unless there is another library more beginner friendly, I would prefer to not go beyond bootstrap, W3.CSS & jQuery as of yet.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: What is a "tyro"? How can something "single-page scroll on half of webpage"? --- _"Please direct me to the correct documentation pages"_ asking for off-site tools is off-topic (see [help/on-topic]).

Comment: this is the github documentation of how the parallax effect was achieved. Go through it. https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/Extension---Parallax  . i got this url from the link you are provided in your question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Tyro is a beginner, a novice essentially. Somebody who just started learning something or at the least isn't very well-versed yet.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Tyro is a beginner, a novice essentially. Somebody who just started learning something or at the least isn't very well-versed yet. I meant SINGLE-PAGE as a complete adjective. On the example I cited, if you scroll your mouse's scroll wheel by one increment the entire display page changes to the next one. This page of stackoverflow, for instance, isn't a single-page scroll. Lastly, I asked for documentation in addition to the answer because being a beginner I may need to read a bit extra. Thanks.

Comment: @divine Thanks. But I intend to use this feature on half of a page not all of it. I guess it isn't possible or may be I am not able to clarify clearly. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Zzz use div tag to limit the height and use overflow auto css. this will display contents inside the div with scrollbar  within the height limit